# Ruby Guard: Is the directory being watched stored in some variable?

Tags: ruby, guard

I'm using Guard to automatically watch a directory and with Guard-Shell execute some bash script, the problem is that I have the Guardfile in a different folder that the one being watched, so I have to use guard with `guard -w /directory/being/watched`.

My question is, **Is there a variable accesible from the Guardfile that will tell me the directory being watched?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Correctly-using-the---watchdir-option

the solution is to run guard in the directory being watched but specify the Guardfile in a different directory:

```
cd /directory/being/watched
BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/projects/foo/Gemfile bundle exec guard -G /projects/foo/Guardfile
```